# Powershell Invalid Class Errors

Tags: powershell

Trying to run the powershell command

```
Get-WmiObject win32_physicalmemory
PS C:\> Get-WmiObject win32_physicalmemory
Get-WmiObject : Invalid class "win32_physicalmemory"
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WmiObject win32_physicalmemory
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

I then read that the wmi database could be corrupt but when I ran

```
PS C:\> winmgmt /verifyrepository
WMI repository is consistent
```

Is it still worth rebuilding the wmi database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before rebuilding the WMI repository, try recompiling the .mof files related to the Win32_PhysicalMemory class. This can resolve issues with missing or unregistered WMI classes.

```
cd C:\Windows\System32\wbem
mofcomp CIMWin32.mof
```

This will recompile the `CIMWin32.mof` file, which includes the definition for the Win32_PhysicalMemory class.